# Which PHP MVC framework follow a standard syntactic coding pattern not solely reliant on the opinion of the framework?

Tags: php, oop

My development background comes from legacy PHP (Wordpress and spaghetti coded PHP into HTML), Ruby on Rails and Javascript, notably AngularJS. The current AngularJS and Angular 2 fiasco is the underlying source behind this question.

I am relatively new to Object Oriented PHP and have taken numerous courses to get up to speed. I have been having a hard time detecting a pattern within the PHP frameworks.

It seemed Laravel would be an obvious pick given my Rails development background, but from what I am seeing, Laravel has designed it's own opinionated patterns like Ruby on Rails. It's learning curve is substantial. I am willing to stay with it because it is really well designed, but feels clunky and bloated.

I have been working with Slim 2, I love it's light-weight modular design and feel that it transitioned me into Object Oriented PHP nicely. I intend to keep it in my tool kit for small projects, unfortunately, it is not in demand with potential employers.

I'm noticing too many inconsistent coding patterns amidst the 'in demand' PHP frameworks. I don't want to stay with Laravel just because of the marketing hype.

I am not looking for a 'which framework is best' answer, the hype doesn't interest me, technical portability is more important. I am hoping more seasoned PHP developers can identify, which of the current in demand full scale PHP frameworks, technically and syntactically conform to a PHP programming standard that is not reliant solely on the opinion of the framework? In other words. If the framework gets shelved, the coding pattern I have learned won't get entirely shelved with it.

Comment: Codeigniter 3 out and it is now owned by a college in USA ( I forgot the name of it ) and it is updated to support a variety of things.

Comment: "I'm noticing too many inconsistent coding patterns amidst the 'in demand' PHP frameworks" - could you please name a few of these patterns or what do you find inconsistent/problematic about their integration in the framework?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to get upset about "inconsistent coding patterns" but insist on "MVC" .

Comment: Frameworks, by design, are opinionated. Auth libraries, ORM libraries, validation libraries, all need some sort of common coding style to make everything nice and uniform. The core PHP OO `$object->method` should be the same in most frameworks. So, pick one, or roll your own.

Comment: @mario To someone coming from my PHP background that didn't involve additions of things like YAML, Twig among other added libraries making PHP almost unrecognizable. The inconsistency does make sense when trying to include these into workflow.

Comment: @GabrielC.Troia I apologize as I am not at my computer to demonstrate actual code. I'll reference just one segment. ROUTES on Laravel look and code differently from its sister framework Lumen. Lumen has similarities to Slim in its route coding. I realize Lumen and Slim are classified as Micro. Another Micro framework Flight follows a similar pattern as Laravel for routes. It's these kind of inconsistencies that are concerning me.

Comment: @anthony On the Ruby side, I was able to pick up other frameworks easily. It was because the Ruby aspect didn't change.  Ideally I would love to stick with Slim and build on what I need as I need it. For freelance projects that's what I'll use. I just came off an interview that had no interest in Slim. I'm in Canada. I'm shying away from Angular prospects right now because I am not sure I'm willing to commit to Angular 2 as I have already taken on React. They're is a lot of similarities between those two. I'd prefer to stay server side now as client side is too unpredictable right now.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something along the lines of an MVC compliant framework. While most PHP frameworks do follow the basics of [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), I have found these to generally follow the same paradigms as most developers would expect.

- [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/)
- [Phalcon](https://phalconphp.com/en/)
- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)

While each of them have their own gotchas and exceptions, they will all provide you **ample** job prospects and have good documentation.

Disclaimer - I have worked as a PHP developer for 10+ years and have been employed at places using these frameworks (in other words to each his own).

Comment: The MVC structure comes easy for me. Syntactically it has been amazing to see how much PHP has changed in its OO life form. I'm going to look at Cake PHP again. It has been surfacing as a prospect in a number of opportunities and has been recommended many times by seasoned PHP developers. It's just hard to avoid the Laravel hype. I'm just trying not to fall into the trap that AngularJS ultimately caused me.